# how can I find ram size of some mobile phones?

Tags: java, mobile, java-me, size, ram

I'm going to create a memory consuming j2me mobile application. The problem is that I don't know average ram size of usual mobile phones and how much memory I can use?

Do you know how can I find ram size of some specific phone model (note that I don't have all of these models in my hand)? Or do you have any idea about keywords I should search for?

As an example searching for *Sony Ericsson T700 Ram size* didn't result to anything.

Comment: This is good question.This kind of questions and the answers are very usefull to managing memory space in the field of mobile application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you want to know what device have how much total memory?

I don't know if there's online service that allow you to query it.
However, if you are willing to do some processing, [Enough Software](http://www.enough.de/home/) (creator of J2MEPolish) have open source device database that contains total memory information.

Just go to http://devices.enough.de/interactivedb/searchdevices.faces and **download current stable devices.xml file**. You'll find 3 files. Look at `devices.xml` and you'll find something like this:

```
<capability name="totalmemory" value="3550208" />
```

There's also devices database called [WURFL](http://wurfl.sourceforge.net). However, I don't have time to check if their database contain `TotalMemory` information.

Hope that helped.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Runtime](http://jcs.mobile-utopia.com/jcs/3677_Runtime.html2) class. Use this code:

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime() ;
System.out.println("freeMemory:> "+runtime.freeMemory());
System.out.println("totalMemory:> "+runtime.totalMemory());
System.out.println("usedMemory:> "+(runtime.totalMemory() - runtime.freeMemory()));
```

Comment: Thank you for the response but as I said I don't have all of those models and I can't run the code on all of them.

Comment: Basically how do you know how much ram space you can use on the mobile phone of your users?

Comment: Use `runtime.totalMemory()`. Its return total ram memory of the mobile.

Comment: I think OP want to know if there's database containing total memory information. Not how to programmatically check total memory.

Answer (score 1):

[JBenchmark](http://www.jbenchmark.com/)  is an excellent place to find information about device capabilities. Just search for the device and look under JVM for "total memory". Or register an account and download the JBenchmark_data_export.xml file for the complete database.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to a friend in another forum (http://www.coderanch.com/t/549476/JME/Mobile/much-ram) I have some information on this.

Furthermore some companies provide more detailed specifications on their models which can be used by developers:  [nokia](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Devices/) , [SonyEricsson](http://developer.sonyericsson.com/wp/) etc.